# Is it possible to access a variable in the Uninstall() proc that tells you the install directory?

Tags: c#, setup-project, custom-action, uninstallation

I have a setup project that installs my service, gui, and a few other files.  It installs them and creates the service and everything looks great!  When the service runs, it creates a few text files and those text files stay in the install folder.

My question revolves around the uninstallation of the service/app.  When I go to uninstall it does everything as expected but ends up leaving the program directory because the newly created text files that are still in there.

Is it possible to somehow get the original install path of the service and application when the Uninstall() proc gets fired up?

EX:

```
//Code to perform at the time of uninstalling application 
public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.Uninstall(savedState);

    try
    {
        //This is the variable I want to NOT be a static set hardcoded path...
        string baseFolder = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\";

        string[] allFileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(baseFolder, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string filename in allFileNames)
        {
            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(filename);
            File.SetAttributes(filename, attr & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        }

        System.IO.Directory.Delete(baseFolder, true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is yes, but it involves jumping through hoops with an extra shim custom action just to pass the `INSTALLFOLDER` property... search 'wix pass property to deferred custom action' to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**
YES!  Just use the SaveState property and pass it along in the chain of the install process thread...

**Solution:**
Add an "Installer Class" file to your project, in this example it's called "InstallerActions.cs".

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class InstallerActions : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public InstallerActions()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Code to perform at the time of installing application
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        //if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();

        CustomParameters cParams = new CustomParameters();
        cParams.Add("InstallPath", this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]);
        cParams.SaveState(stateSaver);

        //Continue with install process
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }

    //Code to perform at the time of uninstalling application 
    public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        //if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();

        CustomParameters cParams = new CustomParameters(savedState);
        string sBase = cParams.GetValue("InstallPath");

        //Continue with uninstall process
        base.Uninstall(savedState);

        try
        {
            //Delete all files in the base folder recursively except service or exe files
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sBase, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                //Check the extention of the filename first
                string sExt = Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower();
                if (sExt != ".installstate" && sExt != ".exe")
                {
                    FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(f);
                    File.SetAttributes(f, attr & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(f);
                }
            }

            //This would delete the base install directory but
            //the installer will do this instead, I just need to
            //clean up everything I made other the the exe's and
            //service files
            //System.IO.Directory.Delete(sBase, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error, just ignore it
        }
    }
}
```

Create another class called "CustomParameters.cs"

```
public class CustomParameters
{
    //Private variables
    private Dictionary<string, string> dParams;

    //Constructor
    public CustomParameters()
    {
        //Reset the dictionary
        dParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public CustomParameters(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        string sKey = "";
        string sValue = "";

        //Import saved state data
        if (dParams == null) dParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var entry in (dynamic)savedState)
        {
            object dKey = entry.Key;
            object dValue = entry.Value;

            switch (dKey.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "System.String":
                    //Save the key
                    sKey = (string)dKey;

                    switch (dValue.GetType().ToString())
                    {
                        case "System.String":
                            //Save the string value
                            sValue = (string)dValue;

                            break;
                        case "System.Int32":
                            //Save the int value
                            sValue = ((int)dValue).ToString();

                            break;
                    }

                    break;
            }

            //Save the keypair to the global dictionary
            dParams.Add(sKey, sValue);
        }
    }

    //Public functions
    public void Add(string sParameterKey, string sParameterValue)
    {
        if (dParams == null) return;

        //Add or update the key
        dParams[sParameterKey] = sParameterValue;
    }
    public void Delete(string sParameterKey)
    {
        if (dParams == null) return;

        //Delete the key if it exists
        if (dParams.ContainsKey(sParameterKey))
        {
            dParams.Remove(sParameterKey);
        }
    }
    public void SaveState(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        if (dParams == null) return;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in dParams)
        {
            if (savedState.Contains(param.Key) == true)
                savedState[param.Key] = param.Value;
            else
                savedState.Add(param.Key, param.Value);
        }
    }
    public string GetValue(string sKey)
    {
        if (dParams.ContainsKey(sKey))
        {
            return dParams[sKey].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a VS setup project, the answer is no unless you saved the location during the original install. The way you do this is to create a registry item in the IDE Registry view and give it the value [TARGETDIR] (case-sensitive) and that will resolve to the actual value. Then you can retrieve it from the registry.

It looks like the problem you're trying to solve is that the uninstall leaves some files behind, so perhaps that's the actual problem that could be fixed in some other way. The uninstall should be removing all the files that it installed and leave only those created by the app in the sane folder.